# Как сделать ScrollBar в PDFViewer в Android?

Tags: java, android, pdf

[Вот](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewerV1/blob/master/android-pdf-viewer/src/main/java/com/github/barteksc/pdfviewer/ScrollBar.java) используемая мною библиотека. Мне нужно сделать Scroll Bar в правой части экрана. Попробовала уже все туториалы, но никак не могу сделать именно Scroll Bar.

```
public class BIt extends AppCompatActivity {
PDFView bit ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bit);
        bit = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.bit) ;
        displayPDF();
    }
    private void displayPDF(){
        bit.enableSwipe(true);
        bit.enableAnnotationRendering(true);
        bit.fromAsset("bit.pdf").load();
    }

}
```

Так выглядит мой код сейчас. Пожалуйста подскажите как сделать Scroll Bar

Comment: а вы в документации к библиотеке смотрели?

Comment: @Andrew да, я пробовала разные методы, но не получилось. Я новенькая в этой сфере, поэтому просила совета у более опытных

Comment: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewerV1#show-scrollbar - это пробовали тоже?